# An array has values in the formar "item1,item2". I want it to be ["item1","item2"]. What should i do?

Tags: jquery, arrays, string

```
 console.log(jQuery("#tickets-expanded input:checkbox[name='ids[]']:checked"));
        jQuery("#tickets-expanded input:checkbox[name='ids[]']:checked").each(function() {
           selected.push(jQuery(this).val());
        });
        alert(selected);

        jQuery("#ids").val(selected);
```

This is my code. Selected array contains elements in the format "2,1". I want it to be ["2","1"]. What should I do?

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the code:

```
var a = "item1,item2,item3";

a = a.split(",");

console.log( a );
```

Output will be:

```
["item1","item2","item3"]
```

Now you can apply this technique on your code at the end. The string you are getting can be `split` and you will get the array.

**Edit:** You have multiple `id` elements? So you can also `split` data among them. Each will contain a value

Comment: You are right. Turns out my #ids is of the type string. So when I try to push an array into it, it automatically gets converted into a string. How can I fix this? I want to store the selected array in my hidden field which is #ids AS AN ARRAY NOT AS A STRING.

Comment: @ArvinthShriram you can not assign array to a single text input. What you can do is let it remain string and whenever you access it first convert it into array and then work with it.

Comment: What if I change the type of the hidden field to an array? I think I can do it by specifying the name as ids[].

Comment: You have multiple `id` elements? So you can also split data among them. Each will contain a value

Answer (score 1):

Thats what its `toString()` returns, if you want a different format construct it manually:

```
str = "[\"" + selected.join("\",\"")​​​​​​​​​​​ + "\"]"​​​​​​;
```

Comment: This is not working. The output I get for `selected[0]` is not `item1` rather `[`

Answer (score 0):

```
selected = '[' + selected + ']';
```

Comment: This is not working. The output I get for `selected[0]` is not `item1` rather `[`

Comment: Your putting it before the jQuery("#ids").val(selected); yes?

Comment: Pls check my query above in my comment to Muhammad Ahmad.

Answer (score 0):

```
'5,6,7'.split(',')
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get an array of selected checkboxes

```
var values = $("#tickets-expanded input:checkbox[name='ids[]']:checked").map(function () {
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: Pls check my query above in my comment to Muhammad Ahmad.